# Arguments length error when using tapply on a matrix

Tags: r, tapply

the following code returns me an "Arguments must have the same length error". Can you please help me in understanding how to fix it?

```
A <- matrix(sample.int(10, size = 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
b <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)

tapply(A, b, mean)
```

I want to compute the average value for each column, grouped by possible values of b. I expected to find 3 values for each column with the average

Comment: Error message says it clearly. `length(A)` and `length(b)` are not same. What are you trying to do? What output do you expect?

Comment: You can't do it for both columns as is. For example, this `tapply(A[,1], b, mean)` works

Comment: ? `apply(A, 2, FUN=tapply, INDEX=b, mean)` or `tapply(A, rep(b, ncol(A)), mean)`

Comment: @RonakShah I wanted to compute the average value for each column, group by possible value of b. I expected to find 3 values for each columns with the average.

Comment: @jogo Thank you, I will try this with my complete dataset!

Comment: @botti23 Now (from your comment) is clear you want: `apply(A, 2, FUN=tapply, INDEX=b, mean)` or `apply(A, 2, FUN=function(x) tapply(x, INDEX=b, mean))`